# Finding the sum of all elements in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to create a 2D array that will find the sum of all elements. I am not inputting my numbers into the 2D array since I am using a driver to check my work. So far I have this - however it will not complie. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static double sum2d (double[ ][ ] array2d)  
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row=0; row < array2d.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col=0; col < array2d[row].length; col++)
        {
            sum = sum + array2d [row][col];
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method is declared to return a `double` but you are returning `sum` which is an `int`.

**Edit:** As @samrap stated in the comments, your code has formatting errors here. You are missing an opening brace `{`.

Comment: Assuming he's not also missing that opening method brace, this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a brace after the method signature

```
public static double sum2d (double[ ][ ] array2d) {  <----- put that in.
```

Also, you need to declare `sum` as `double`.

```
double sum = 0;
```

Note that if a method returns `double`, and `sum` has type `int`, you *can* do `return sum`. The problem here is that `sum + array2d [row][col];` is a `double` so can't be assigned back to an `int` without a cast (but that's not what you want to do).

Comment: Is it not possible to write `double d = 1.0; int a = d;` like that without casting?

Comment: @Gendarme No, that doesn't compile. It needs to be `int a = (int) d;`, but that removes the fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

Declare sum as double instead of int

Answer (score 0):

package Homeworks;

public class HomeWork86 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
int[][] a = {
        {1,1,2}, 
        {3,1,2}, 
        {3,5,3}, 
        {0,1,2}  
    };
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
      for (int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++){
        sum+=a[i][j];

      }
      System.out.println(sum);
        sum=0;
    }
```

}
}